# windows form con visual studio

Tags: windows-forms

recién estoy empezando, y me cuesta mucho este lenguaje, me podrían ayudar con el código de este ejercicio.
En un formulario coloque un panel con un Label sobre dicho panel, con el texto
Titulo 1. Sobre el formulario coloque otro Label con el texto Titulo 2 . Agregue
cuatro botones. Dos lo utilizaran para ubicarlo en la posición 0,0 y los otros dos para volverlo a la posición original. Utilice las propiedades Top y Left para realizarlo

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Primero lo que deberías hacer es ubicar los labels en el formulario. Una vez hecho esto, vas a necesitar 2 variables.

```
double label1X = This.Label1.Top
double label1Y = This.Label1.Left
```

Una vez realizado esto, tenes que hacer lo mismo con el otro Label.
En el primer botón simplemente seteas el Top y Left del Label.

```
This.label1.Top = 0
This.label1.Left = 0
```

Y con el segundo botón asignas las variables que guardamos a las posiciones correspondientes de x e y.

```
This.label1.Top = label1Y
This.label1.Left = label1X
```

Comment: Pero eso seria para los labels?

Comment: entiendo que debo hacerlo con los buttons que son 4, no con las labels

Comment: Lo que estamos haciendo acá es, primero guardamos las posiciones iniciales en 2 variables para poder recuperarlas mas tarde, después modificamos las propiedades según indica el ejercicio y por ultimo modificamos nuevamente las propiedades para que vuelva a su estado inicial. Estas funcionalidades deberían estar en los eventos [ButtonClick](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=netframework-4.8) de los botones correspondientes